# Calling a protocol method results in a crash

Tags: ios, swift4

I use protocol to call a func and then I get a crash . I know how to fix that ,but I want to exact know, why it can't work ,and why that can work . I think the problem may be is method dispath problem.

```
protocol Testable where Self : UIView{
    func update()
}

class JKD : UIView,Testable{
    func update() {
        print("JKD")
    }
}

func test(a : Testable){
    a.update()
}

let j2 : JKD = JKD.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
test(a: j2) // it will crash
```

And this crash have mush of way to fix , like this :

```
@objc protocol Testable where Self : UIView{
    func update()
}
```

or this :

```
protocol Testable{
    func update()
}
```

and if the func use Generic,it also can fix the crash

```
func test<T : Testable>(a : T) {
    a.update()
}
```

or if the class in extension inherit the protocol,it can fix the crash too.

```
class JKD : UIView{}
extension JKD : Testable{
    func update() {
        print("JKD")
    }
}
```

so , in this case I want to know, why just the first way will crash .

Answer (score 1):

From the Swift 5 release [notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_beta_4_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2_beta_4?preferredLanguage=occ),

> Protocols can now constrain their conforming types to those that
> subclass a given class. Two equivalent forms are supported:
>
> ```
> protocol MyView: UIView { /*...*/ }
> protocol MyView where Self: UIView { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> Swift 4.2 accepted the second form, but it wasn’t fully implemented
> and could sometimes crash at compile time or runtime. ([SR-5581](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5581))
> (38077232)

Seems like they have fixed existing issues in Swift 5. It works fine on Xcode 10.2 beta 4.